# Dividing arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm defining a function in python in this way:

```
def calculate(y1,y2,y):
    l=np.log(3)
    ya=np.array(y1)/(np.array(y)*np.array(l))
    yb=np.array(y2)/(np.array(y)*np.array(l))
    return (ya,yb)
```

but when I run my script (even if everything works) I get the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
ya = np.array(y1)/((np.array(y))*(l))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
yb = np.array(y2)/((np.array(y))*(l))
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried examining the 2 values that you are using in the division - the problem will probably become obvious if you do this

Comment: Yes, the y array may contain zeros..how can I skip the problem and just put a zero in ya/yb when the corresponding value in y is a zero too?

Comment: Skip the problem and use zeros: `ind = y!=0; ya = np.zeros_like(y); ya[ind] = y1[ind] / y[ind]`

Comment: @eryksun: Very nice solution. If the array `y` contains floats rather than integers, one should probably use `ind = abs(y) > tol` where `ṫol` is a small numerical tolerance value, instead of `!=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because there is either a `0` or a `np.inf` value in the denominator array.

There's not a lot you can do other than clean up `y` before it gets to `calculcate`

```
def calculate(y1, y2, y):
    if not isinstance(y, np.ndarray):
        y = np.array(y)

    if not np.isfinite(y):
        print 'bad y array values'
        return

    elif np.sum(y == 0) > 0:
        print 'zero values in y'
        return

    # the rest of your code
```

Note this will stop the `RunTimeWarning` but will return nothing so the function that calls `calculate` will have to deal with that.